# WordPress Quickly Scrolls to the Bottom

Tags: wordpress, performance, scroll

On this page of my website https://advertising-excellence.com/project/audio-visual-branding/

If you try to scroll down slowly to read the text, it skips quickly to the bottom of the page. From the bottom of the page if you try to scroll up slowly it quickly jumps to the top of the page. I've tried with the mouse and arrow keys and I get the same problem. I have not found any other page of the website yet with this issue. I've looked at the html for the page and can't see anything unusual.

Comment: After scrolling down your project-content section adds a css transformation.
transform: translateY(-2111.02px);

Answer (score 0):

After scrolling down your project-content section adds a css transformation.

```
<div class="project-narrow-col project-content floating-content" style="transform: translateY(-2111.02px);"> ...</div>
/*transform: translateY(-2111.02px);*/
```

If you scroll up the transformation will change again:

```
<div class="project-narrow-col project-content floating-content" style="transform: translateY(0px);"> ... </div>
/*transform: translateY(0px);*/
```

The CSS function translateY () repositions your element horizontally by the given value.

You could override the transform within you child-themes style.css

```
.project-narrow-col.project-content.floating-content {
    transform: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!